# CentOS networking: ping doesn't reach a single private IP for no apparent reason

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm running a CentOS 7 VM in VirtualBox and all works fine except for the fact that one single IP from our internal network isn't reachable. The host is macOS Sierra and pinging this IP from it works without any problems. This IP is reachable also from every other client on this network, it's just this CentOS machine that doesn't find it.

The CentOS VM has two network interfaces each bridged to a separate interface on the host. Every interface connects to a different subnet. There are no other network issues.

Does anyone have an idea where this problem could originate? I myself wasn't able to find a solution and after a few weeks of pointless web searching, I'm really lost.

I'd be very thankful for all help in troubleshooting this and will provide requested information.

Best,
Georg

EDIT: forgot to mention that the device did respond to pings up until two months ago. It was also disappearing from time to time (meaning it stopped responding in the same manner as now, otherwise it was connected and working) but after restarting the network.service on the CentOS machine it was again reachable.

EDIT 2: Output of `netstat -rn`

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.254    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s3
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s8
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s8`

Comment: Can you add the results from `netstat -rn` and the IP you're trying to ping?

Comment: Of course:
`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.254    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s3
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp0s8
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s3
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 enp0s8`

And the IP in question is 192.168.4.1.

Comment: Ugh, this looks awful. Sorry for that – not a frequent user and don't know how to paste it better :/

Comment: you should add it to your question, there you can have a code block

Comment: It looks like you've got two default gateways?  And i'm not sure about the effects of the genmask 255.255.252.0 in the last route entry.

Comment: Both the thing with the two gateways and the netmask are the result of the configuration of the whole network. And because it used to work for most of 2017, with those few interruptions, I assumed that this shouldn't be a problem. Any ideas how could I potentially investigate this?

Comment: No idea how you could investigate this.  I've checked with a colleague who spends the day supporting our network: you should have only one default gateway.  In your last line, the genmask 255.255.252.0 excludes direct access to 192.168.4.1, so the second line in your route should read something like `192.168.0.0  192.168.0.1 255.255.0.0 UG 0 0 0 enp0s8`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue: just changed my configuration to use only one default gateway and all works.

Thank you, Gerard, for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: There is a tool you could have used for investigation: traceroute.

Comment: I did try traceroute but it didn't move further than the first hop. Also I just had no idea that two default gateways could potentially interfere that much – I thought that each NIC could have its own.

Comment: And the first hop was ...?

Comment: A firewall but after that nothing more happened.

Comment: Did you expect to hit the firewall when trying to reach 192.168.4.1?

Comment: Yes, I did but I assumed that this shouldn't be a problem since every client behind the firewall could ping 192.168.4.1. To be honest, the network here hasn't been built up by me so it is quite weird (also without documentation). Which is why I run into problems ever so often and can't understand where they originate.